# Sum childrens in two tables of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I Have 3 tables:

```
a (id,date,ckey) b(id,a.ckey,hht,hha) c(id,a.ckey,date_ini,date_fin)
```

where B keeps all the activities to be done and their respective hours in 2 places (hht,hha), while c saves the activities carried out with its initial and final date (to determine the hours executed the dates are subtracted).

Now I need to know, for each record in A how many hours you have assigned (B) and how many hours you have completed (C)

actually i have this:

a:

```
+----------+----------+------------+
|    id    |   date   |     ckey   |
+----------+----------+------------+
|    1     |2018-01-20|     18     |
|----------|----------|------------|
```

b:

```
+----------+----------+--------+--------+
|    id    |  a.ckey  |  hht   |   hht  |
+----------+----------+--------+--------+
|    1     |    18    |    2   |    3   |
|    2     |    18    |    2   |    5   |
|    3     |    18    |    0   |    7   |
+----------+----------+--------+--------+
```

c:

```
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|    id    |  a.ckey  |        date_ini      |        date_fin      |
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|    1     |    18    | 2019-01-23 13:30:00  | 2019-01-23 14:00:00  |
|    1     |    18    | 2019-01-23 14:00:00  | 2019-01-23 14:30:00  |
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I need this:

```
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|    id    |  a.ckey  |         hours        |         hours2       |
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|    1     |    18    |           19         |           1          |
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I get this:

```
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|    id    |  a.ckey  |         hours        |         hours2       |
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|    1     |    18    |           38         |           37.5       |
+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
  (b.hht+b.hha) AS hours, 
  (SUM(b.hht+b.hha) - 
    FORMAT(IFNULL((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, c.date_ini, c.date_fin)/60),0),2)) AS hours2
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.key=b.akey 
INNER JOIN c ON a.key=c.akey 
GROUP a.ckey
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have multiple rows in tables `b` and `c` for each value of `ckey` you need to do the aggregation within a subquery, otherwise you get duplicated rows leading to incorrect sums.

```
SELECT a.id, a.key, b.hours, FORMAT(c.minutes/60, 2) AS hours2
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT akey, SUM(hht+hha) AS hours
           FROM b
           GROUP BY akey) b ON b.akey = a.key
LEFT JOIN (SELECT akey, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date_ini, date_fin)) AS minutes
           FROM c
           GROUP BY akey) c ON c.akey = a.key
ORDER BY a.id
```

Output:

```
id  key     hours   hours2
1   18      19      1.00
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1199d3/4)

Comment: Jobs! Thanks for the suggestion, obviously there are more rows and more tables, but i get the point!. Love u ! @nick

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an m-to-n-join, try UNION ALL instead:

```
select ckey, sum(hours) as hours, sum(hours) - sum(hours2) as hours2
from
 (
   SELECT ckey, (b.hht+b.hha) AS hours, NULL as hours2
   FROM b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ckey, NULL AS hours, 
      FORMAT(IFNULL((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, c.date_ini, c.date_fin)/60),0),2)) as hours2
   FROM c
 ) as dt
group by ckey
```

If you actually need columns from table a put this Select in a Derived Table and join to it.

Answer (score 1):

please check this

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT SUM(hha + hht) from b where b.ckey = a.ckey) hours, 
  FORMAT((SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, c.date_ini, c.date_fin)/60) from c where c.ckey = a.ckey),2) as hours2 
FROM A
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fd65/7)

Comment: Thanks for the Help however @nick code works perfectly :)