# fetch count(number of invoices generated) from 2nd table and sum(total amount of orders) from 3rd table - MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cust` (
  `cId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cId`)
);

INSERT INTO `cust` (`cId`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Danish'),
(2, 'Dilkash'),
(3, 'Dilshad');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inv` (
  `iId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iId`)
);

INSERT INTO `inv` (`iId`, `cId`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ord` (
  `iId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `ord` (`iId`, `cId`) VALUES
(1, '50'),
(1, '80'),
(2, '40'),
(3, '20'),
(3, '30'),
(4, '90'),
(5, '60'),
(5, '40');
```

I want to get the number of invoices generated on customer and the sum of all orders. There are 3 tables cust,inv,ord which stands for customers,invoicec,orders

:::::::::::::::WORKING FINE::::::::::::::
I tried to get the total number of invoices generated with customer's name using this query...its working fine...

```
mysql> select cust.cId,cust.name,count(inv.iId)
from cust left join inv on cust.cId=inv.cId group by cust.cId;
+-----+---------+----------------+
| cId | name    | count(inv.iId) |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|   1 | Danish  |              3 |
|   2 | Dilkash |              2 |
|   3 | Dilshad |              0 |
+-----+---------+----------------+
```

:::::::::::::::WORKING FINE::::::::::::::
then I tried to get the sum of amount of all invoices generated with grouped by customer... its also working fine

```
mysql> select cust.cId,cust.name,count(inv.iId)
from cust left join inv on cust.cId=inv.cId group by cust.cId;
+-----+---------+----------------+
| cId | name    | count(inv.iId) |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|   1 | Danish  |              3 |
|   2 | Dilkash |              2 |
|   3 | Dilshad |              0 |
+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

::::::::::::::PROBLEM IS HERE::::::::::::::::::

but when I try to get the COUNT and SUM in the same result its not working... it is counting the orders not the invoices..

```
mysql> select cust.cId,cust.name,count(inv.iId),sum(ord.cId)
from cust left join inv on cust.cId=inv.cId left join ord on inv.iId=ord.iId group by cust.cId;
+-----+---------+----------------+--------------+
| cId | name    | count(inv.iId) | sum(ord.cId) |
+-----+---------+----------------+--------------+
|   1 | Danish  |              5 |          220 |
|   2 | Dilkash |              3 |          190 |
|   3 | Dilshad |              0 |         NULL |
+-----+---------+----------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

please correct my last query... its showing 5,3,0 which is the number of orders not the number of invoices.. it should show 3,2,0....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum childrens in two tables of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298518/sum-childrens-in-two-tables-of-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scalar subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a6d18a162d75cb0e57fbb39b2cb1eb3)**

```
 select cust.cId,cust.name,(select count(iId) from inv b where cust.cId=b.cId ),
sum(ord.cId)
from cust left join inv on cust.cId=inv.cId left join ord on inv.iId=ord.iId 
group by cust.cId
```

OUTPUT:

```
cId name      invcnt    sum(ord.cId)
1   Danish     3         220
2   Dilkash    2         190
3   Dilshad    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting dups because of `LEFT JOIN`, same query with `DISTINCT` should work, e.g.:

```
SELECT cust.cId, cust.name, COUNT(DISTINCT inv.iId), SUM(ord.cId)
FROM cust LEFT JOIN inv ON cust.cId=inv.cId 
LEFT JOIN ord ON inv.iId=ord.iId 
GROUP BY cust.cId, cust.name;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56688b5/3/0)**.

Comment: thank you sir.. it works...

(another question)
maybe you are right sir, but at first I was doing without left join but the problem was same

please review this query also
select cust.cId,cust.name,count(inv.iId),sum(ord.cId) from cust,inv,ord where cust.cId=inv.cId and inv.iId=ord.iId group by cust.cId;

Comment: You can't do it without `left join` as it will not show the records which are not present in other table.